# Update MYSQL table From Excel

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba

I would like to import an table from MySQL, edit/add data, and then update the the table in MySQL. I can currently import and add records, but am not sure how to update existing records.

My data is the following structure:

test_db2_id | Email_Address | First_Name | Last_Name | Address | etc...

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

If I run the below code, it just appends the updated data to the existing data. When I try to use test_db2_id as a field, I get the following error message.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
Dim MyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim table1 As String, field1 As String, field2 As String, sqlstr As String
Set MyConn = New ADODB.Connection

MyConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=dbTest;" & _
        "USER=***;" & _
        "PASSWORD=***;" & _
        "Option=16427"
        
table1 = "test_db2"
field1 = "Email_Address"
field2 = "First_Name"

With Sheets(2)
For i = 5 To 10000
    If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Exit For
    sqlstr = "INSERT INTO " & table1 & " SET " _
    & field1 & " = '" & Cells(i, 2) & "'," _
    & field2 & " = '" & Cells(i, 3) & "'"
    
    MyConn.Execute sqlstr
Next i
    
    End With
    
On Error Resume Next
MyConn.Close
Set MyConn = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Table Updated"

End Sub


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2JdV.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHtba.png
```

Comment: when one of the fileds is a primary key or unique use INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE

Comment: If (eg) ColA represents the record id and has a value, then it's an existing record, and you would use "update test_db2 set ... where id=[your id value]".  Otherwise if there's no id it's a new record, and you'd use insert instead.

Comment: I tried using the ID and I get an error message. Please see the image in the updated post